# Modifying some C++ code to update a record

Tags: c++

I only want it to update server_record. Don't send any messages. What can I remove so it doesn't say "New record of players online is: 2839". Can I remove everything under `query.str("")`?

I have no idea what `char buffer[50]` does. I don't want to mess anything up. And how can I get current time in C++? I want to insert the current time in the table too, to see when record was set.

```
void Game::checkPlayersRecord()
{
if(getPlayersOnline() > lastPlayersRecord){
    Database* db = Database::instance();
    DBQuery query;

    lastPlayersRecord = getPlayersOnline();
    query << "UPDATE `server_record` SET `record` = " << lastPlayersRecord << ";";
    db->executeQuery(query.str());
    query.str("");

    char buffer[50];
    sprintf(buffer, "New record of players online is: %d", lastPlayersRecord);
    AutoList<Player>::listiterator it = Player::listPlayer.list.begin();
    while(it != Player::listPlayer.list.end()){
        (*it).second->sendTextMessage(MSG_EVENT_ADVANCE, buffer);
        ++it;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: if you don't understand c++, don't touch it... chances are you ruin something else somewhere

Comment: This code is already suspicious. For instance, why is a "check" function non-const and doing an update?!

Comment: Better no consts than inconsistent consts.

Agreed though, this function is definitely bizarre.

Answer (score 4):

Better get someone who knows this stuff. What you're asking isn't exactly rocket science, but is still pretty easy to get wrong if done by an inexperienced person.

Answer (score 0):

Upon casual inspection, yes, delete everything under (but not including) `query.str("");` Hopefully you have a way of testing it before pushing this change live and breaking the app. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty obvious what these blocks do, so unless they have some hidden stuff, this is the part which updates the database with the record value.

```
void Game::checkPlayersRecord()
{
    if(getPlayersOnline() > lastPlayersRecord){
        Database* db = Database::instance();
        DBQuery query;

        lastPlayersRecord = getPlayersOnline();
        query << "UPDATE `server_record` SET `record` = " << lastPlayersRecord << ";";
        db->executeQuery(query.str());
        query.str("");
    }
}
```